# DataFrame.apply oddly returns a dataframe instead of series under certain circumstances

Tags: python, pandas

**UPDATE**: the following behaviour might have been a bug in Pandas 1.4.4 (which was the version I used up to now). Upgrading to Pandas 1.5.2 yields a Series both for `test1` and `test2`, which is what I was expecting.

I need to handle receiving empty dataframes (besides non-empty ones) like this one:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[], 'b':[]})
```

I derive a series from the dataframe I get (also the non-empty ones, which works well).
The `apply` function unexpectedly returns a DataFrame instead of a Series if both

- the input DataFrame is empty and
- I use a function in the `apply`'s lambda.

```py
def f(x):
    if x%2 == 0: return True
    else: return False

test1 = df.apply(lambda row: 'foo' if f(row[0]) else 'bar', axis='columns')
test2 = df.apply(lambda row: 'foo' if True else 'bar', axis='columns')
```

`test1` is a (empty) DataFrame while `test2` a (empty) Series, which I expect it to be (with non-empty DataFrame df, always a Series is returned).

I know I could write a simple workaround, but I would really like to know what's happening here.

Comment: I get an empty series for both (pandas 1.5.2.).

Comment: `df.apply` returns a series or DataFrame per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Also both return an empty Series for me.